# Flutter error: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderSemanticsGestureHandler#59d86 relayoutBoundary=up5

Tags: flutter, dart

full error: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPointerListener#50b80 relayoutBoundary=up6 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
package:flutter/…/rendering/box.dart:1
Failed assertion: line 1930 pos 12: 'hasSize'

this is return tree of my listView.separeted: ListView return sliable, sliable return inkwell, inkwell return Material, and material Return Widget function that return ListTile.
This is my ListTile function before i add code that give me error

```
return ListTile(
      title: Text(
        item.name,
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 26, color: Colors.black),
      ),
      subtitle: Text('${description}', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, color: Colors.black)),
      trailing: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 17),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
          children: [Text("Проверено ${execution}/${item.checkListPoints.length}"), Text("Качество ${finalResult}/100")],
        ),
      ),
      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
        horizontal: 16,
        vertical: 16,
      ),
    );
```

and this is after

```
return ListTile(
      title: Text(
        item.name,
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 26, color: Colors.black),
      ),
      subtitle: Text('${description}', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, color: Colors.black)),
      trailing: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 17),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
          children: [
            Text("Проверено ${execution}/${item.checkListPoints.length}"),
// I add this Row
            Row(
              children: [Text("Качество ${finalResult}/100"), getFace(finalResult)],
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
        horizontal: 16,
        vertical: 16,
      ),
    );
```

getFace function return me Icon depend on finalresult value, how i can fix this error and Insert icon after text "Text("Качество ${finalResult}/100")"

I tried to change icon size in getFace function, but it didn't work. This is getFace function

```
Widget getFace(checkListResult) {
  if (checkListResult < 50) {
    return Icon(
      Icons.sentiment_very_dissatisfied,
      color: Colors.red,
      size: 10,
    );
  } else if (checkListResult >= 50 && checkListResult <= 60) {
    print("50-60");
    return Icon(Icons.sentiment_dissatisfied, color: Colors.redAccent, size: 10);
  } else if (checkListResult > 60 && checkListResult <= 70) {
    print("60-70");
    return Icon(Icons.sentiment_neutral, color: Colors.amber, size: 10);
  } else if (checkListResult > 70 && checkListResult <= 80) {
    print("80-90");
    return Icon(Icons.sentiment_satisfied, color: Colors.lightGreen, size: 10);
  } else if (checkListResult > 80 && checkListResult <= 100) {
    print("100%");
    return Icon(
      Icons.sentiment_very_satisfied,
      color: Colors.green,
      size: 10,
    );
  } else {
    print("иначе");
    return Icon(
      Icons.sentiment_very_satisfied,
      color: Colors.green,
      size: 10,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: try mainAxisSize.min in Column

Comment: @HamzaSiddiqui mainAxisSize.min didn't work

Comment: fix the height and width of list tile and try mainAxisSize.min in Row too

Comment: @HamzaSiddiqui mainAxisSize.min in Row fix error, thanks

Answer (score 1):

To fix this problem add mainAxisSize.min in Row

```
Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
          children: [
            Text("Проверено ${execution}/${item.checkListPoints.length}"),
            Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [Text("Качество ${finalResult}/100"), getFace(finalResult)],
            )
          ],
        ),
```